# Crack line in GLTF from texturing image

Tags: blender, threejs-editor

[GLTF image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLuDx.jpg)
After UV unwrapping and texture painting the object looks fine but I am seeing a crack line If I see it from the certain angles or when I zoom it out. Looks fine when zoomed in.

I tried multiple UV unwrapping option but it didn’t help.

Thanks